# Authentication for Local Active Director to MySQL via LDAP

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, active-directory

I'm not getting a proper solution for connecting my local **Active Directory** to **MySQL**. 
Got to know about a php library ***adLDAP***, which can make this happen according to the following **documentation**:

[adLDAP documentation for Active Directory](http://adldap.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php?id=documentation)

> I'm unable to find out where to begin with this as it is new to me.
>   Expecting any useful and kick-start answer from the developers out there.

Thanks.